# How to generate a MongoDB Atlas collection automatically once a business or user signs up for my app?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mern, mongodb-atlas

My app is built in the MERN stack. Once a new business signs up for the app, I want to auto-generate a mongoDB collection for them. I need every business to have its own Monggodb collection but right now I am doing it manually and integrating it with their account. How can I automate this? My app is hosted in Google Cloud.

So far, what I am doing is manually creating the collection everytime someone signs up. Usually takes 24 hours for me to do so. I really do not have any idea on how to do this and where to start.

Comment: MongoDB collections will be created automatically when a document is added.  Is there a special option that needs to be set that requires explicitly creation?

Comment: @Joe does that mean that I will just create a dynamic mongodb_uri with a dynamic collection name and that will automatically create the collection for me?

Comment: If you use a database name in the URI that doesn't exist, it will be created when you insert the first document.